# @@SERVERNAME is NULL

Tags: sql-server

How do you fix the issue when 
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
returns null

Dave

PS: I just figured this out but it wasn't obvious... Answer to follow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sp_dropserver 'OLDNAME'
sp_addServer 'NEWNAME', 'local'
```

The 'local' part is important, it doesn't work without it ( I think it attempts to add the server as a remote linked server without it)

Comment: Correct, without the 'local' it creates it as a remote server.

Comment: Weirdly the documentation failed to mention it (grr)